# I need to make the two elements with the logos to stay centered.

Tags: html

https://tradeka.bg/home/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8/
Before there were 3 elements and there was no problem, but know is only two and they stay on the left. I need them centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the div surrounding the .team-member divs to be:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
```

rather than:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the col-md-4 into col-md-6. You should also add col-lg-6 to both partners.